# How to track down a page reload in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am debugging a page that has a jquery dialog that contains a textbox and an ok button.

When a user hits enter, the page is reloading and the textbox ID & value are being passed to the page reload as get parameters.  e.g.

```
http://example.com?tex_box_id=text_entered_in_text_box
```

I cannot figure out what is causing this behavior and can't figure out how to best track it down since the page itself is reloading.

I have tried stepping through all the jquery code, but did not have any luck.   I can only assume that somebody somewhere attached a key press listener, but I can't figure out who.  I know I can work around this by preventing theirs from running, but I still really want to figure out why it is happening.

Note that this does NOT happen if you click the OK button, only if you hit enter when you are in the text box

Comment: some form arround the input that is submitting?

Comment: There is a remote possibility that pressing return just submits a form.

Comment: Would be my guess, too. You probably won't find anything in your JavaScript because it just looks like a form submit via GET

Comment: Insufficient info included here for anything other than wild guesses.  If you want to increase your chances of getting this solved, include either a link to the page in question (with instructions for reproducing the problem) or include all relevant HTML/JS in your post.

Comment: Will try to add a link or HTML shortly.   When I looked at the HTML of the page, I did not see a <form> tag, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will disable all of the forms on the pages from being submitted:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```

While this will "solve" your problem, you should target your form specifically, and use custom JavaScript behavior for submitting the data (e.g. using $.ajax).

For more advanced debugging use the following:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  var breakpoint = 1; // Place a breakpoint on this line!
  // Then use the "step out of current function" button to
  // continue through the JS that gets executed... much of it
  // will likely be native code, but if you pay attention to
  // the native function names, you should eventually see the
  // event that is causing the reload.
});
```

Comment: I understand your suggestion for working around the problem.  Do you have any idea how to track down _why_ it is happening?  I don't actually believe my dialog is necessarily a form.  It has a textbox, but then just a jquery button for the OK button.  When I look at the HTML in Firebug I don't actually see a <form> tag

Comment: I don't use Firebug actively, but when I did it was much like Chrome's "Inspect" feature... so I'm assuming you're seeing the active DOM. If that's the case, and there still isn't a FORM element, then I recommend overriding the "keydown" function, and then using firebug's "step" functionality to step through the code being executed after that. I'll modify my answer with the JavaScript you would add the breakpoint to in a bit.